# Java: How to replace last 18 bits of a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am getting last 18 bits (to save space) of a UTC timestamp from sensors. Not on my side I want to generate the complete UTC time from those 18 bits by replacing the last 18 bits of current timestamp with the one I am getting from Sensors. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @pedromss yes, I tried couple of things be refering stack over flow only but since I am not at all conformable with bit manipulation (or never tried it before) did not put those solutions here. In future I will post what I tried also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
currentStamp &= ~0x3FFFF; // Set the last 18 bits to 0
sensorStamp &= 0x3FFFF; // Set all except the last 18 bits to 0
currentStamp |= sensorStamp; // combine
```

Comment: thanks a lot Oleg, looks like this is what like I need.